# how to get all days name having same to and from times in json?

Tags: javascript, json

```
var data = {
"fri": {
  "to_time": "16:00",
  "from_time": "10:00"
},
"mon": {
  "to_time": "16:00",
  "from_time": "14:00"
},
"sat": {
  "to_time": "16:00",
  "from_time": "10:00"
},
"sun": {
  "to_time": "13:00",
  "from_time": "10:00"
},
"thu": {
  "to_time": "16:00",
  "from_time": "14:00"
},
"tue": {
  "to_time": "16:00",
  "from_time": "10:00"
},
"wed": {
  "to_time": "16:00",
  "from_time": "10:00"
}
}
```

how to get all days having same to and from_time?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: You must show us what you have tried.

Comment: do you mean days which have `to_time` and `from_time` same as those of some other day? or `to_time = from_time`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take an object and the wanted same times for collecting the days.

```js
var data = { fri: { to_time: "16:00", from_time: "10:00" }, mon: { to_time: "16:00", from_time: "14:00" }, sat: { to_time: "16:00", from_time: "10:00" }, sun: { to_time: "13:00", from_time: "10:00" }, thu: { to_time: "16:00", from_time: "14:00" }, tue: { to_time: "16:00", from_time: "10:00" }, wed: { to_time: "16:00", from_time: "10:00" } },
    groups = ['from_time', 'to_time'],
    grouped = Object.entries(data).reduce((accumulator, [day, object]) => {
        var key = groups.map(group => object[group]).join();
        (accumulator[key] = accumulator[key] || []).push(day);
        return accumulator;
    }, Object.create(null));
    
console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: it's always a question how to name the variable either by content or by function.

Comment: no, it's passed to the `accumulator`, as `reduce`'s signature. the first parameter of the callback is the accumulator, the second it the item of the array and while `Object.entries` returns an array of arrays with key and value of the object, this array gets a destructuring for `day` and `object`.

Comment: i took the smaller edition of it, the nutshell edition, the whole book is too much to read ... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = { fri: { to_time: "16:00", from_time: "10:00" }, mon: { to_time: "16:00", from_time: "14:00" }, sat: { to_time: "16:00", from_time: "10:00" }, sun: { to_time: "13:00", from_time: "10:00" }, thu: { to_time: "16:00", from_time: "14:00" }, tue: { to_time: "16:00", from_time: "10:00" }, wed: { to_time: "16:00", from_time: "10:00" } };

var myArr = [];
//Loop through object
for (var i in data) {
  for (var j in data) {
    if (i != j && data[i].from_time == data[j].from_time && data[i].to_time == data[j].to_time) {
      if (myArr.indexOf(i) == -1) {
        myArr.push(i);
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(myArr);
```

Comment: I created you a snippet, and renamed your array

Comment: The result does not actually answer the question